# SPFX save array inside item response to display in render react

Tags: spfx, react, pnpjs

I am facing simple issue where I need to get value of an expanded person field in react. I am receiving the title and was able to assign it to a variable, but my need is to automatically get the value assigned to the predefined interface fields just like other response values(Division and Duedate) which are not array. I tried below. Please help

```
ListItems:{"Assignee":[],"Division":"","DueDate":""}; //This is in the state
const AssignmentList:any = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("AssigneeTracker").items.getById(parseInt(id)).select("Assignee/Title","Division","DueDate").expand("Assignee/Id").get();
  console.log(AssignmentList);
  var test=AssignmentList.Assignee[0].Title;
  console.log(test);//here I am receiving the value
  reactHandler.setState({ListItems:AssignmentList});
```

> Tried Rendering as below

```
<div className={styles.CellStyle}> 
{this.state.ListItems.Assignee.map(assigne=>{return <li key={assigne}>{assigne}</li>})}</div>
```

Below image is the response : 
[image: Response from List]

[image]

Comment: how is the interface for ListItems defined?

Comment: You can also click the link in your error message in the console to get more information.

Comment: export interface IPnPPeoplePickerState {
    ListItems:{"Assignee":[{"Title":""}],"Division":"","DueDate":""};
}
I am trying below almost trying to ge there....<div className={styles.CellStyle}>{this.state.ListItems.Assignee.map((item,index)=>{<li>{item[0].Title}</li>})}</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your render method is trying to render the entire assignee `{assigne}`, but React doesn't know how to render that object.

Try changing your render to:

```
<div className={styles.CellStyle}> 
{this.state.ListItems.Assignee.map(assigne=>{return <li key={assigne["odata.id"]}>{assigne.Title}</li>})}</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I did similar to that like below.<br>{test.length ? test : <p>test</p>}----var test=this.state.ListItems.Assignee.map((item,index)=>{return <li key={index}>{item.Title}</li>})

Comment: Yup the important thing to notice here is you can't render the whole Assignee item, you have to reference specific properties (like ".Title").